# Access WebSphere Application Server resources from the adapters

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst

Which is the relation between the adapters and WAS?

Is the adapter executed inside the webcontainer?

For example using java inside the adapters do I have access to the WAS resources like jdbc datasources or distributed map cache or ....?

Can I use the dynacache of WAS for HTTP Adapters? For caching the adapter response and also for caching the final services, invoked from the adapter, response.

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can access these resources using Java through adapters. I have used adapters calling Java and JDBC datasources to return stored procedure out parameters (not supported in the SQL adapters). Here is an article to invoke EJB 3.1 statelesss session beans from an adapter and the EJB client: https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/blogs/e4210f90-a515-41c9-a487-8fc7d79d7f61/entry/part_5_integrate_the_ibm_worklight_adapter_with_ejb_3_1_application?lang=en

Comment: Great!, thank you. I really think all the features that WAS can give to Worklight for integration scenarios using Java should be much more popular than what they are. At least I do not see any metion to this in the common slides and presentations.